# plt.quiver plots wrong vectors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the vectors A and B using matplotlib but somehow, it doesn't plot correctly. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = [2,4]
B = [1,2]
X = [0,0]
Y = [0,0]

plt.quiver(X,Y,A,B, color=['b','r'],angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.show()
```

Here's the plot:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgnsN.png)

A is somehow plotted as (2, 1) and B as (4,2). Can someone explain this?

Comment: `A = [2,1]`, `B = [4,2]`?

Comment: Based on the description of the arguments in the function's docstring, your images looks correct to me (two vectors originating at the origin in the same direction with different magnitudes)

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html), `help(plt.quiver)`:

> Call signature:
>
> `quiver([X, Y], U, V, [C], **kw)`
>
> X, Y define the arrow locations, U, V define the arrow directions, and C optionally sets the color.

In your code:

```
plt.quiver(X,Y,A,B, color=['b','r'],angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
```

You are telling Matplotlib that `A` represents the horizontal direction of your vectors, and `B` represents the vertical direction.

Instead, you want `A` and `B` to be the actual vectors (starting from `X` and `Y`). Hence, you need to write them as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

U = [2,1]
V = [4,2]
X = [0,0]
Y = [0,0]

plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V, color=['b','r'],angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.show()
```